# how to calculate field of view of the camera from camera intrinsic matrix?

Tags: opengl, camera, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I got camera intrinsic matrix and distortion parameters using camera calibration.

The unit of the focal length is pixels, i guess.

Then, how can i calculate field of view (along y) ?

Is this formula right?

```
double fov_y = 2*atan(height/2/fy)*180/CV_PI;
```

I'll use it to parameters of

```
gluPerspective()
```

Answer (score 36):

OpenCV has a [function](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#calibrationmatrixvalues) that does this. Looking at the implementation (available on [GitHub](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/2.4/modules/calib3d/src/calibration.cpp#L1778)) we have given an image with dimensions w x h and a camera matrix:

[image: camera intrinsic matrix]

the equations for the field of view are:

[image: field of view y]    [image: field of view x]

Comment: what is fx and fy. what is cx and cy

Comment: I'll leave the explanation of those terms to the OpenCV documentation on [Camera Calibration and 3D Reconstruction](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html)

Answer (score 1):

In continuation of [@mallwright's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41137160), here is a bit of Python/numpy code to compute the field of view from the image resolution and focal lengths (in pixels):

```py
import numpy as np

# Prepare
w, h = 1280, 720
fx, fy = 1027.3, 1026.9

# Go
fov_x = np.rad2deg(2 * np.arctan2(w, 2 * fx))
fov_y = np.rad2deg(2 * np.arctan2(h, 2 * fy))

print("Field of View (degrees):")
print(f"  {fov_x = :.1f}\N{DEGREE SIGN}")
print(f"  {fov_y = :.1f}\N{DEGREE SIGN}")
```

Output:

```
Field of View (degrees):
  fov_x = 63.8°
  fov_y = 38.6°
```

Note that this assumes that the principal point is at the center of the image and that there is no distortion, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64840278/1447415).